# Where is in VERTX $VERTX_HOME/conf/langs.properties config location?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jruby, rack, vert.x, jrubyonrails

I can not find where to place language properties config with VERTX I want to run Rack with Vertx (for rails):

here https://github.com/isaiah/jubilee/wiki/Running-as-vertx-module

it suggests to add this line:

```
rackup=isaiah~mod-rack~0.1.1:org.jruby.jubilee.JubileeVerticleFactory .ru=rackup
```

into the the configuration file:

```
$VERTX_HOME/conf/langs.properties
```

But i can't find it...

Comment: Are you using Vert.x 2? This module does not work with 3 as it states on the readme.

Comment: i am on vertx 3